# why concat is throwing error for merging 2 array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Hi' i'm getting `Error`

> concat is not a function

what i'm trying is

```
    searchResults:any;   // inside class export
    results:any


 this.candidateSearch.postSearch(this.searchedInput,"candidateSearch").then((result)=>{

     this.results = result;

     console.log(this.results.details);       

    this.searchResults = this.searchResults.concat(this.results);   // throwing error      


          }, (err) => { 

        });
```

**my result is coming in this format:**

```
{
    "details": [{
        "company_name": "Cybrain Software Solutions",
        "skills": "php,laravel",
        "package": "15 lakh",
        "location": "Bengaluru",
        "industry": "Software",
        "job_type": "permanent"
    }, {
        "company_name": "Floret Media Pvt Ltd",
        "skills": "php",
        "package": "10 lakh",
        "location": "Bengaluru",
        "industry": "software",
        "job_type": "per"
    }]
}
```

**my question: i want to concact the previous results**

EDIT: I want the `searchResults` array to be in this format `{"details":[{},{},{}]} after concatenation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are now trying to concat is an **object**. So what we need to do is to actually concat the array that is **inside** your **object**:

```
searchResults = {details:[]};

...

this.searchResults.details = 
    this.searchResults.details.concat(this.results.details);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the array

```
searchResults:any = [];
```

Comment: do i need to to do anything with `searchResults.details` then `concat` or above code will work?

Comment: still i'm getting this error ==> `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.searchResults.concat is not a function`

Comment: check if they are of same type otherwise cast accordingly

Comment: ya both of them are of same type please see posted code above

Comment: you want to merge. this.results.details or this results?

Comment: i want the `searchResults` `array` to be in this format `{"details":[{},{},{}]}` after `concatenation`

Comment: i don't know that how to begin this

Comment: click on the link